# Having trouble finding the BN code in Pay pal commerce

Tags: paypal

Need to find the NB code to connect Paypal to markeplace CS-cart. I can Find every code and number except for this one. Pay pal are useless in their help

Looked everywhere in Paypal ( I think) but cant find and am writing more here than neede to make up 220 characters :(

Answer (score 0):

Instructions to get a BN code (or equivalent PayPal-Partner-Attribution-Id) are in [the multiparty docs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/multiparty/accept-payments/#link-bncode). If none has been assigned to you during communications to be a PayPal partner, then you do not have one and do not need one.

Some multiparty APIs require being an approved partner to use them. So depending on what you are trying to do, you may need to be an approved PayPal partner in order to be live with that integration. This approval is a separate issue from having or not having a BN code, but again may be required depending on what you are trying to do, the specific APIs being used and in what way.